# AHK for Save Dialog: Navigate to desktop and jump to field filename

Tags: autohotkey

I was using this Autohotkey script for a while:

```
; Windows Explorer Save Dialog
; hitting CTRL D goes to address bar, jumps to full desktop path, then goes to filename for the user to override
#IfWinActive ahk_class #32770
    ^D::
        Send !D
        String := "%UserProfile%\Desktop"
        SendRaw %String%
        Send {ENTER}
        Send !D
    return
#IfWinActive
```

It stopped working. Probably a Windows 10 update changed something in the file save dialog.

Now using the script above (hitting CTRL+D) still opens the desktop location, but goes to the top right "Desktop Search" (instead of the filename).

Also changing the last `Send !D` to `Send !N` did not help.

Also `Send {TAB}` does not help, Windows ignores it. The focus seems to be stuck to the Search field.

Comment: Seems like to me the whole saving process could be automated, instead of messing around with the save file dialog hotkeys. But well, to mention one of the few bad practices in this, you shouldn't use capital letters unless you actually want to. Right now you're sending `Alt+Shift+D`, instead of `Alt+D`. Though, it seems like the extra shift in there doesn't seem to hurt the hotkey in the save file dialog. But instead of diagnosing the AHK code, can you say if normally just pressing `Alt+N` goes to the filename field or not? I'm my end it does, and your code works with `Alt+N` at the end.

Comment: The script triggers with CTRL+D. But thanks, I just noticed when I do within the Save dialog: ALT+D, then it jumps to the location field on top, I hit enter, then I hit ALT+N and it does not jump to the fieldname field. So it's a bug in Windows!

Comment: For the automation of the saving. My goal is to save the file (from any save dialog) to the desktop. What other way do you suggest?

Comment: Yes, your hotkey is `Ctrl+D`, I meant the Send commands, don't use capital letters unless you actually want them. And since u mean intercepting **any** save file dialog (I thought this would've been for something more specific), I guess it gets more complicated then. Probably doable, but don't know from on top of my head how you'd do it. But I think I found a solution for you, see the answer I'm about to write to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the discussion in comments, I was actually able to reproduce the issue you're encountering and found the issue.
The `Alt+N` hotkey in the save file dialog to switch focus to file name field indeed doesn't seem to work if the focused control never left any of the text input controls. By setting the focused control at least once to something other than one of the text input controls, then the `Alt+N` hotkey seems to work as expected.

Ok, so here's the working code.

```
^d::
    ControlFocus, DirectUIHWND2, A
    SendInput, % "!d%userprofile%\Desktop{enter}!n"
return
```

So first we're focusing the `DirectUIHWND2` control, could've used an other control in the save file dialog as well, doesn't matter which one we use.
And if you don't know how to figure out windows' controls, one easy way is to use "Window Spy". It's a neat little AHK script that comes with every AHK installation.
You'll find it from your AHK install directory.
Should be called `C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\WindowSpy.ahk`. Or if you have an older AHK installation, it may also be a compiled script file named `AU3_Spy.exe` (or something like that, I forget)
And the [`A`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ActiveWindow) parameter in the [`ControlFocus`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlFocus.htm) command means the active window.

And then I used just one send command. No need to use multiple send commands, or create some variable, as you do in your code.
And also used `!d` and `!n` instead of `!D` and `!N`.
Don't use capital letters in send commands, unless you actually want them.
`!D` and `!N` actually send `Ctrl+Shift+D` and `Ctrl+Shift+N`, instead of `Alt+D` and `Alt+N`, which is what I assume you actually were after.

Also, used [`SendInput`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#SendInputDetail) instead of just `Send`. `SendInput` is the preferred method due to it being faster and more reliable (more about this from the documentation)
Though, one concern I have, is maybe it could even be too fast. Seems work fine for me every single time, but if you were to have trouble, you can maybe split it up to multiple commands, adding a bit of [`Sleep`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Sleep.htm) in between. Or maybe could even switch back to `Send` and use [`SetKeyDelay`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetKeyDelay.htm).

Another approach for this, could be with using control set -commands.
E.g. first focusing a control, as I did in my code, and then using e.g [`ControlSetText`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSetText.htm).